# Why thead-per-multiple-connections model is considered better than thread-per-connection model?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, network-programming, scheduler

Most of the times, you will hear that thread-per-multiple-connections model (non-blocking IO) is much better than thread-per-connection model (blocking io). And reasoning sounds like "Thread-per-connection approach creates too many threads and a lot of overhead is associated with mantaining so many threads". But this overhead is not explained.

- Common misconception is that scheduling overhead is proportinal to the number of all threads. But it's not true, scheduling overhead is proportinal to the number of runnable threads. So in typical IO bound application, most of the threads will actually be blocked on IO and only several of them will be runnable - which is not different with "thread-per-multiple-connections" model.
- As for context switching overhead, I expect that there should be no difference, because when data arrives kernel should wake up a thread - selector thread or connection thread.
- The problem may lay in IO system calls - kernel might handle kqueue/epoll calls better than blocking IO calls. However, this does not sound plausible, because it should not be a problem to implement O(1) algorithm for selecting blocked thread when data arrives.
- If you have many short-lived connections, you will have many short lived thread. And spawning a new thread is an expensive operation (is it?). To solve this problem, you may create thread pool and still use blocking I/O.
- There might be OS limits for the number of threads that could be spawned, however they might be changed with configuration parameters.
- In multicore system, suppose different sessions access same shared data. If we're talking about connection-per-thread model, this might cause a lot of cache coherency traffic and may slow down the system. However, why not to shedule all these thread on the single core if only one of them is runnable at the given point in time? If more than one of them is runnable, it means that they should be scheduled on different cores. However, to achieve same performance in thread-per-multiple connections model, we would need to have several selectors and they will be scheduled on different cores and will access same shared data. So I don't see differences from cache perspective.
- In GC environment (take Java for example), garbage collector should understand which objects are reachable by traversing object graph starting with GC roots. GC roots include thread stacks. So there is more work for GC to do on the first level of this graph. However, total number of alive nodes in this graph should be the same for both approaches. So no overhead from GC point of view.
- The only argument, I agree with, is that each thread consumes memory for its stack. But even for this case, we may limit size of stacks for these threads if they don't use recursive calls.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: The two new points you just added are correct as well. Note, that non-blocking IO does *not* imply one thread. Usually, it's one thread per core for servers that are meant to scale. The single-threaded `select` or `poll` based design is basically obsolete. Modern designs such as epoll, kqueue or IOCP use multiple threads to drain a queue of IO events (essentially).

Comment: @usr, Thanks for your answer, I'm adding new points as they come to my mind. I hope this question will help many people realize that its only thread stack overhead that should influence their decision.

Comment: Straw man. I'm not aware that anybody has claimed that thread-per-connection is slower as per your title, and if they have they're wrong. The usual claims, which I agree are dubious, are that NBIO, async, etc., are more *scalable,* and that's what the body of your post is actually about.

Comment: @EJP, I agree that scalable better descibes those claims. I've changed the title.

Answer (score 1):

There are two overheads:

1. Stack memory. Non-blocking IO (in whatever form you are using it) saves the stack memory. An IO is just a small data structure now.
2. Reduction in context switching and kernel transitions when load is high. Then, a single switch can be used to process multiple completed IOs.

Most servers are not under high load because that would leave little safety margin against load spikes. So point (2) is relevant mostly for artificial loads such as benchmarks (meant to prove a point...).

The stack savings are the 99% reason this is being done.

Whether you want to trade off dev time and code complexity for memory savings depends on how many connections you have. At 10 connections this is not a concern. At 10000 connections a thread-based model becomes infeasible.

The points that you state in the question are correct.

Maybe you are confused by the fact that the "common wisdom" is to always use non-blocking socket IO? Indeed, this (false) propaganda is being communicated everywhere on the web. Propaganda works by repeatedly making the same simple statement and it works.